# Sequence contains no matching element, FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

```
public ActionResult Update(string id)
{
    Device record = new Device(); // OK
    record = record.Find(new Guid(id), service); // OK

    if (record.secondValue.HasValue) // <--- 
          record.secondSelectList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == record.secondValue.ToString()).Selected = true;
    return View(record);
 }
```

The above code finds a device for a given ID, then sets the DropDownList **If** *secondValue* has a value, if not then skip.

The code works perfectly, but in many actions in many controllers I have to to put an **IF**  condition to check if *xxxValue* is indeed have a value.

I can't do this directly:

```
record.secondSelectList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == record.secondValue.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

because at any time FirstOrDefault may return a null reference, which will instantly will throw an exception because of using the **.Selected** property.

OK, my question is how to set the DropDownList with no need of using If conditions?

I imagine instead of using FirstOrDefault(), I will use SetSelected().

```
record.secondSelectList.SetSelected(i => i.Value == record.secondValue.ToString());
```

Where is SetSelected() method I will handle the null result.
How can I do this?

Comment: The question may seem silly but I don't know which topic to search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it inline:

```
record.secondSelectList.FirstOrDefault(i => { if (i.Value == record.secondValue.ToString()) { i.Selected = true; return true; } return false; });
```

Or, probably more clearly:

```
foreach (var listItem in record.secondSelectList) {
    if (listItem.Value == record.secondValue.ToString()) 
        listItem.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 LINQ is for queries, not edits. Since the OP is changing data, a `foreach` + `if` is more appropriate here.

Comment: The first option gives compilation error: 
Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,bool>'. For the second option, I see more statements unlike the original code above in my question. I mean if the solution is to use foreach, then I'll stick to the If condition better.